# Mocking DoNothing a private void method of a class - using PowerMockito

Tags: java, methods, mocking, mockito, powermockito

public method a class is being tested and inside the public method its calling a private method. I want to ignore`(doNothing)` when the private method is called.

```
 Myclass{

    public void someMethod( String some, File file, long age ,String name ){
        -----somecode----
        callprivateMethod(File file, long age, String name); //want to mock and Donothing
        -----somecode----
    }
}
```

Have Done the following

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Ignorethisclass.class,MyClass.class})
MyClass iMyClass= Mockito.spy(new MyClass());
```

Following code is giving null pointer excetion with:

> [0]org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:65)  StackTraceElement

```
doNothing().when(iMyClass, PowerMockito.method(MyClass.class, "callprivateMethod")).withArguments(Mockito.any(File.class),Mockito.any(long.class),Mockito.any(String.class));
```

---

I tried this too as I read somewhere to do like this
The following code is giving a null pointer exception

```
doNothing().when(iMyClass, "callprivateMethod", Mockito.any(File.class),Mockito.any(Long.class),Mockito.any(String.class));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Tried this too:                                                       
               'PowerMockito.doNothing().when(MyClass, PowerMockito.method(MyClass.class, "callprivateMethod",File.class,long.class,String.class)).withArguments(Mockito.any(File.class),Mockito.any(long.class),Mockito.any(String.class));'
'[0] org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:65) StackTraceElement'

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock "MyClass" using powermock :

```
MyClass iMyClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
```

Full example:

```
//MyClass.java
import java.io.File;

public class MyClass {
    private void callprivateMethod(File file, long age, String name){
        throw new RuntimeException("avoid!");
    }

    public void someMethod(String some, File file, long age , String name ){
        System.out.println("-----somecode----");
        callprivateMethod(file, age, name);
        System.out.println("-----somecode----");
    }

}


//MyClassTest.java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.io.File;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doNothing;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void someMethod() throws Exception {
        MyClass iMyClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
        doNothing().when(iMyClass, "callprivateMethod", any(File.class), any(Long.class), any(String.class));
        iMyClass.someMethod("some", new File(""),22,"name");
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
-----somecode----
-----somecode----
```